# g++: error: LDFLAGS=-Wall: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, codeblocks

beginner here and running CodeBlocks for the first time in my Raspberry Pi 3B. I wanted to include opencv, pigpio and multithreading in my c++ project and downloaded opencv and piggpio already. In codeblocks, i added the compiler flags which are:

`CFLAGS=-Wall`pkg-config --cflags opencv`-std=c++11 –c 
LDFLAGS=-Wall`pkg-config --libs opencv` -std=c++11 -lpigpio -lrt -lpthread

And when I compiled & built my code, i got the error "g++: error: LDFLAGS=-Wall: No such file or directory"

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
} 


//Build Log from CodeBlocks

-------------- Build: Debug in main (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g CFLAGS=-Wall -I/usr/include/opencv -std=c++11 –c  -c /home/pi/Desktop/CodeBlocks3/main/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
g++  -o bin/Debug/main obj/Debug/main.o  LDFLAGS=-Wall -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_face -lopencv_freetype -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hdf -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_video -lopencv_plot -lopencv_reg -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_phase_unwrapping -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_viz -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_text -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ml -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core -std=c++11 -lpigpio -lrt -lpthread  
g++: error: LDFLAGS=-Wall: No such file or directory
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Comment: `LDFLAGS=-Wall`  doesn't seem like a valid linker flag, I'd remove it and try again. `-Wall` is a compile option for turning on all (most) warnings.

Comment: Also, `std=c++11` should not be included as part of `LDFLAGS`.

Comment: `LDFLAGS=-Wall` isn't even a linker flag at this stage. The whole thing is interpreted as a filename.

Comment: Works perfectly now, thank you